# Unable to remove Navigation Bar - Android Tablet: 4.2.2

Tags: android, navigationbar, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm attempting to remove the navigation bar programatically using the most commonly found method on the internet - however the navigation bar continues to appear.

I've debugged the method and it is not throwing an exception - so I'm really not sure why we can't seem to hide the Navigation Bar using the following code:

(any suggestions are greatly appreciated)

### Source:

```
try
{
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui"}); 
proc.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext
```

Comment: This is undocumented code and an unsupported area. There is no guarantee this will ever work.

Comment: A little bird once told me if there's a will there's a way... 

I have full root access - there MUST be a way of disabling it somehow. : )

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this, somewhere after you have set your content's view

To hide your navigation bar

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

To hide your keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

For more on the navigation bar, since it is what your question explicitly asks for, take a look here: [Hiding the Navigation Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Comment: I need to permanantly hide the keyboard - this does not hide it for me at all 

P.S.

The devices is rooted - so that is not a problem - however your solution does not seem to hide the navigation bar when I implement it between onCreate and setContentView